# Check box using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am currently learning to use Selenium with Python, and I am writing an autofill program.

I want to be able to check a box on the form to confirm I have read terms and conditions, but I cannot figure out the proper search to do so.

This is the HTML of the object to be clicked:

```
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; w…roll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
```

So far, I have tried: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("iCheck-helper").click()` where `driver` is my WebDriver object. This has been unsuccessful though.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Provided `html` is not for a target check-box. I guess you need an `<input>` element

Answer (score 0):

I used `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'I have read and agree to the')]").click()` to find the text and select it.